# How to iterate over a CSV file that is converted to a Dictionary multiple times so it can display different output depending on users' input

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, while-loop

I've been learning Python 2.7 for the past 2 months so I am a real beginner.  I am working on a menu-driven program that has shows the user a menu that contains 6 choices labeled 0 to 5.  I then created a while loop that allows users to choose from the menu.  So several users can choose item 1 as an example and get different output depending on their input.

I added a while loop, and tested choice 1 to see if I can get 2 different users to use it and get an output that is different.  By choosing 1, the program asks the user for input and his answer prints out certain items from the csv file.  During the first round, the program prints with no problem.  Then, a second person clicks on item 1 again and provides a different answer. I expect the program to print out a different list based on the 2nd user's input from the same csv file.  But to  my dismay, the program delivers no output.  It looks like the csv file isn't being read again.

I have done research on how to have the program read the file over and over again but to no avail!  I've spent over 5 hours on this without success.  Here is my code to open the CSV which I tried in two ways.

First method:

```
import csv

input_reef = csv.DictReader(open("reef_master.csv"))
```

Comment: Second method, I created a function.

```
import csv

def open_reef_csv(input_reef):
    with open("reef_master.csv", "rU") as f:
        input_reef = csv.DictReader(f, dialect=csv.excel)
    for row in input_reef:
        print input_reef
```

Comment: You can't iterate over a file more than once unless you close and reopen it or rewind it. `csv.DictReader`s don't have a rewind function, so you'll have to close the file, reopen it, _and_ create a new `csv.DictReader` to read it.

Comment: A friendly advice: If you want people to find an error in your code, it is usually a good idea to post the code that doesn't work, not just the code that works (in this case, the problem is easy to identify, but that won't always be the case). Also please be mindful of the indentation of your code. Your second snippet contains an indentation error that would break the program.

Comment: Your approach to read the file each time a new user makes an entry doesn't seem efficient. Why not read the entire file in to once and then access that data from the variable each time. If the file changes, close the program and open it again, or have a 'reload_data' function to re-import the data.